# Prove that a subset of sequence space is not totally bounded

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm trying to answer the following question:

Let $M=\{\text{sequences of real numbers }\{x_i\} \text{ with}\underset{1<i<\infty}\sup|x_i| < \infty  \}$

Define $d(\{x_i\},\{y_i\})=\underset{1<i<\infty}\sup|x_i - y_i|$.

Let $p\in M$ be given by the sequence $p=\{0,0,0,...\}$, the zero sequence.

Let $A = \{\{x_i\}\in M \text{ | } d(\{x_i\},p)\leq 1\}$

Prove that A is bounded but not totally bounded.
\end

In the past when I have proven that a set in a sequence space is not totally bounded, I have made use of a common distance between points in the set, constructing $\epsilon-\text{balls}$ based on this common distance. I don't have the option here and I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: For boundedness, note $A = \overline{B}_p(1)$ is the closed (unit) ball centred at $p = 0$. Just to add an alternative proof for total boundedness (which admittedly is probably not what you want, i.e. an $\epsilon > 0$ for which $A$ cannot be covered with $\epsilon$-balls), note $M = \ell^\infty$ is an infinite dimensional Banach space and so the closed ball $A$ is not compact. But compactness in metric spaces is equivalent to completeness and totally bounded. $A$ is complete, being a closed subset of a complete space, and therefore can't be totally bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every sequence in A can be built from sequences and sums and scalar multiples of sequences of the form $(0,...,0,1,0,...)$. Each of these elements are a distance of one from each other so take $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ and you will not be able to cover thisset with a finite number of balls of radius $\epsilon$ so A cannot be totally bounded.

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading the directions but I did not take it that the sequences are of the form (0,...,0,1,0,...). I assumed that a sequence like $1\over{2^{n-1}}$ is a member of A. Perhaps I'm not interpreting this distance function correctly?

Comment: yes a sequence like that is a member of A but it can also be written as a sum of the sequences I suggested.